Convergence of Improper Integral Involving Logarithmic Terms and Parameter
I am analyzing the convergence of the following improper integral and need to determine the range of the parameter $\beta$ for which it converges:
$$
I(\beta) = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t \left(t + \frac{3}{2} \log \left(t + \frac{1}{2}\right) - \log (t) + \frac{1}{2}\right)^{\beta + 2}} \, dt. 
$$
This integral is improper due to the singularity at $ t = 0 $ and the infinite upper limit. I am particularly interested in the behavior of the integral near $ t = 0 $ and as $ t \to +\infty $. Can someone help me find the range of $\beta$ such that this integral converges?
Thank you!
